# How to edit style of output text of return statement in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, styles, size, return-value, font-size

How can I change the font size of the return value?
Or what other method can I do?

[image: My codes and value]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputDecoration` class has a property named `errorStyle`.

You can set fontSize from there.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/errorStyle.html